# IIS Requests for Static Content Not Timing Out Properly

Tags: iis, connection-timeout, static-content

We are running IIS7 and have noticed some very long running requests that are exceeding all of our time out settings.  Many requests are some simple static content files like simple .js or .css & .txt files.

Some of the requests show status codes 404 and other but some show status 200.  These requests are showing as running as long as 3,000,000 milliseconds while all settings should be preventing this.

We do have compression enabled.  We are using IIS Logging.  Most

- We do have compression enabled
- We are using IIS Logging
- Most requests should be immediate or very small files

Anyone know why these requests would not be getting timed out by IIS?